# Prove existence of certain partial limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I’ve recently encountered the following question:

Given a sequence $a_n$ such that
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}~ \lvert a_{n+1}-a_n \rvert \geq 1$, prove that if $a_n$ has more than 1 finite partial limit then it has 2 partial limits $L_1, L_2$ such that $\lvert L_1-L_2 \rvert \geq 1$.

While this is very intuitive, I’ve had a hard time trying to prove it. I have tried a proof by contradiction but it didn’t lead me anywhere. 
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this even true? What about the sequence $1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5,\ldots$? It has only one finite limit point, $1$.

Comment: But this sequence doesn’t satisfy the condition specified in the question

Comment: Yes it does, fix any $n$ and see what you get.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki your sequence doesn't satisfy the condition, because it only has one finite limit point and not more than one. However, the sequence given by $1, 10, 1.5, 11, 1, 12, 1.5, 13, 1, 14, 1.5, 15, ...$ should satisfy the condition as it has the two limit points $1$ and $1.5$ and no other. What do you think?

Comment: @MushuNrek the whole point of the sequence I gave is that it only has one finite limit point - this is a counter example to the statement the original asker is trying to prove.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki but having more than one limit point is one of the assumptions, is it not? I don't see your point.

Comment: @MushuNrek this seems to work! So there was probably an error in the question, odd. Thanks a lot.